# Open GitHub issues with a commit

Tags: github, git-commit

Title pretty much sums it up.

I can close issues with `Fixes #123` but is it possible to open them with a keyword?

Comment: Ideally you won't want to be **intentionally** creating new issues *as* you're committing. You can always prefix your commit with the issue to reference the issue, but I don't believe it's possible to actually *raise* an issue from a commit.

Comment: I'm in a situation where I found that that the issue I closed via a commit, still exist, so, I removed the feature, now I need to reopen it with a commit.

And I'll be surprised too...